# Multilevel neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to complete the following tensorflow tutorial and (attempting problem 4): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/3_regularization.ipynb

However, I think I might be setting up the arrays of weights below wrong. As soon as I change `hidden_layer` to `[image_size * image_size,1024,num_labels]` (i.e. just one hidden layer), this works fine. Currently I am getting `NaN`s for the loss.

**One possible solution** is that the block

`for i in range(1,len(weights)-1):
        relus = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(relus, weights[i]) + biases[i]),p_hide)`

is causing the problems since I am destroying the past value of relus and Neural Nets need them to do backpropagation. In fact when there is one hidden layer this block does not get executed.

```
batch_size = 128
hidden_layer = [image_size * image_size,1024,300,num_labels]
l2_regulariser = 0.005
p_hide = 0.5

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
    # at run time with a training minibatch.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    # Variables.
    weights = [None]*(len(hidden_layer)-1)
    biases = [None]*(len(hidden_layer)-1)
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        weights[i] = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer[i], hidden_layer[i+1]]))
        biases[i] = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer[i+1]]))

    # Training computation.
    relus = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights[0]) + biases[0]),p_hide)
    for i in range(1,len(weights)-1):
        relus = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(relus, weights[i]) + biases[i]),p_hide)
    logits = tf.matmul(relus, weights[len(weights)-1]) + biases[len(weights)-1]

    loss = 0
    for weight in weights:
        loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(weight)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf_train_labels))+ l2_regulariser*loss


    # Optimizer.
    global_step = tf.Variable(0)  # count the number of steps taken.
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.5, global_step, decay_steps=20, decay_rate=0.9)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)  


    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

    relus = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights[0]) + biases[0])
    for i in range(1,len(weights)-1):
        relus = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(relus, weights[i]) + biases[i])
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(relus, weights[len(weights)-1]) + biases[len(weights)-1])

    relus = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights[0]) + biases[0])
    for i in range(1,len(weights)-1):
        relus = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(relus, weights[i]) + biases[i])
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(relus, weights[len(weights)-1]) + biases[len(weights)-1])

######################
# The NN training part
######################
num_steps = 3001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print("Initialized")
  for step in range(num_steps):
    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    # Generate a minibatch.
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels, global_step : int(step)}
    _, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    if (step % 500 == 0):
      print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
      print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
      print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(
        valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
  print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better initialize your weights:

```
tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer[i], hidden_layer[i+1]], stddev=0.1)
```

And most of all, you should **lower your learning rate** to something around `0.01`, `0.001`...

I think your get a loss of `NaN` because the learning rate is too high and it breaks the network (you get exploding weights).

Comment: that certainly seemed to do the trick. But can I just ask how you picked up on the learning rate being too high? Is there an exponentiation step in the neural nets? Or some sort of thumb rule to initialise?

Comment: In general you don't want to have a learning rate higher than `0.1`. The best way to see how well the network is training is to plot the loss (you can do it with Tensorboard, see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html)), if you see the loss oscillating too much and going up it might indicate that you have a too high learning rate.

Comment: And for weight initialization, they need to have a low variance (`<0.1`), see [this post](http://deepdish.io/2015/02/24/network-initialization/)